# using locks to control access to non thread safe libraries

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, locking

I'm working on converting a single threaded application to be a multi threaded one.

One of the libraries we use, according to their documentation is not thread safe. So to get around this the answer is to use locks (at least that's my understanding so far..)

So I kick off my threads:

```
Parallel.ForEach(recordList, Sub(record) ProcessRecord(record))


Public Sub ProcessRecord(ByVal record As UploadRecord)
    Dim controller As New UploadController()
    controller.ProcessRecord(record)
End Sub
```

In the class UploadController(), I've added a lock object.

```
private thisLock As Object = new Object()
```

I then use this lock to control access to calls to my non-thread safe library.

```
SyncLock (thisLock)
                    structureTemplatefs = IO.File.OpenRead(GetVersion(record, validationTemplatePathElement) & structureTemplateElement)
                    validator = New FileValidator(structureTemplatefs, record.FileData, True)

                    'Get all errors... 
                    result = validator.Validate(FileValidator.ValidationEngineType.Structure, True)
                End SyncLock
```

AND:

```
SyncLock thisLock
                        record.FileData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                        cellValue = excelUtility.GetCellFormulaValue(record.FileData, sheetNo, GetConfigSetting(GenericConfigSection.VALIDATION_CELL_RANGE_NAME), fileName)
                    End SyncLock
```

However, its not working. Is it because each thread creates its own instance of UploadController() and therefore there are multiple locks?

Answer (score 0):

On further reading of the following:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx

In particular the following:

> Protected Data. If lockobject is a Shared variable, the exclusive
>   lock prevents a thread in any instance of the class from executing the
>   SyncLock block while any other thread is executing it. This protects
>   data that is shared among all the instances.
>
> If lockobject is an instance variable (not Shared), the lock prevents
>   a thread running in the current instance from executing the SyncLock
>   block at the same time as another thread in the same instance. This
>   protects data maintained by the individual instance.

As a result I've modified my lock to be Shared.
This appears to have resolved my issue.

Comment: While this may work, compile, not throw errors. I would encourage you to do performance profiling with relevant data that you're moving to parallelism for. I say this because to me it looks like a large portion of your parallel code is going to be blocked waiting on thread synchronization. Does the documentation of the class say it has shared instances that are not thread safe? Or that a single instance of the class is not thread safe? If is is the second, you may be able to not use locks and gain the full power of your parallelism.

Comment: Thanks David. The documentation is not very detailed. It just mentions that its not thread safe. I tested without the locks and the results were unpredictable. however having implemented the locks, I've been able to test with large volumes of data and the results were good and predictable and still have noticeable performance gains over the single threaded approach.